# How to add data attribute to options in haml while using association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am actually working on an ROR application and actually stuck with one thing. I am trying to add data-attribute to options of a select menu. I have tried many things but nothing worked.

Here is the code for select

```
- options = { collection: Table.active_leads.includes(:table1).all , input_html: {class: 'form-control'}, label_method: :get_label_text, label: "Select"}
- options[:selected] = params[:add_to_job] if params.has_key? :add_to_job
= f.association :job, options
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you try `input_html: {class: 'form-control', data: {attribute: "value"}}` ?

Comment: this actually adds data attribute to select instead of option tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Run this way**

```
 %select.class#id
    -@data.each do |d|
      %option {value: d.value , data-attribute:"value" } 
         =name
```

or create manually and run loop.

Comment: Actually I need data-atribute on option tag

Comment: My code uses a model function "get_label_text" to get the option's inner html. This code doesn't allow me that